# RoboSpice + Jackson2 ignores JsonProperty while serializing POJOs

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, robospice

I am developing an Android app where I use RoboSpice + Google HTTP Client  + Jackson2 for handling calls to the JSON REST API.

I am unable to use `@JsonProperty` - it is always silently ignored during serializing the object and Java variable names are used instead.

I've went through many StackOverflow answers, unfortunately without any success.

My POJO definition looks like the following:

```
package org.something;


import android.content.Context;

import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.something.client.utils.SystemInfo;

public class ClientNode {
    @Key
    private String id;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="os_type")
    private String osType;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="os_version")
    private String osVersion;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="os_architecture")
    private String osArchitecture;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="app_version")
    private String appVersion;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="memory_usage")
    private int memoryUsage;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="current_network_interface_type")
    private String currentNetworkInterfaceType;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="current_network_mobile_type")
    private String currentNetworkMobileType;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="device_model")
    private String deviceModel;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="device_manufacturer")
    private String deviceManufacturer;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="current_network_mobile_carrier")
    private String currentNetworkMobileCarrier;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="power_battery_charging_state")
    private String powerBatteryChargingState;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="power_battery_charging_type")
    private String powerBatteryChargingType;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="power_battery_level")
    private int powerBatteryLevel;

    @Key
    @JsonProperty(value="power_battery_health")
    private String powerBatteryHealth;


    public ClientNode() {
        // Required by Jackson2
    }


    public ClientNode(Context context) {
        SystemInfo systemInfo = new SystemInfo(context);

        this.osType = systemInfo.getOsType();
        this.osVersion = systemInfo.getOsVersion();
        this.osArchitecture = systemInfo.getOsArchitecture();
        this.appVersion = systemInfo.getAppVersion();
        // TODO add cpu load
        this.memoryUsage = systemInfo.getMemoryUsage();
        this.currentNetworkInterfaceType = systemInfo.getCurrentNetworkInterfaceType();
        if(this.currentNetworkInterfaceType.equals("mobile")) {
            this.currentNetworkMobileType = systemInfo.getCurrentNetworkMobileType();
            this.currentNetworkMobileCarrier = systemInfo.getCurrentNetworkMobileCarrier();
        }
        // TODO add network strength
        this.deviceModel = systemInfo.getDeviceModel();
        this.deviceManufacturer = systemInfo.getDeviceManufacturer();
        this.powerBatteryChargingState = systemInfo.getPowerBatteryChargingState();
        this.powerBatteryChargingType = systemInfo.getPowerBatteryChargingType();
        this.powerBatteryLevel = systemInfo.getPowerBatteryLevel();
        this.powerBatteryHealth = systemInfo.getPowerBatteryHealth();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I tried also to use syntax of `@JsonProperty("something")` - still does not work.

This is code responsible for making actual request:

```
package org.something;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpContent;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.octo.android.robospice.request.googlehttpclient.GoogleHttpClientSpiceRequest;

import org.something.api.ApiHelpers;
import org.something.api.ApiUriBuilder;
import org.radiokit.joint.client.api.models.plumber.resource.architecture.ClientNode;
import org.something.api.responses.SystemInfoUpdateResponse;

public class SystemInfoUpdateRequest extends GoogleHttpClientSpiceRequest<SystemInfoUpdateResponse> {
    private final static String LOG_TAG = "SystemInfoUpdateReq";

    private final String clientNodeId;
    private final Context context;

    public SystemInfoUpdateRequest(Context context, String clientNodeId) {
        super(SystemInfoUpdateResponse.class);
        this.context = context;
        this.clientNodeId = clientNodeId;
    }


    @Override
    public SystemInfoUpdateResponse loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "loadDataFromNetwork: start");

        JsonHttpContent content = new JsonHttpContent(new JacksonFactory(), new ClientNode(context));

        HttpRequest request = getHttpRequestFactory().buildPutRequest(new GenericUrl(new ApiUriBuilder("xxx", "ClientNode", this.clientNodeId).build()), content);

        request.setParser(new JacksonFactory().createJsonObjectParser());
        request = ApiHelpers.addApiHeaders(request);

        return request.execute().parseAs(getResultType());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried @JsonProperty("os_type")?

Comment: Yes I have tried this. I've found out that `@Key("something")` works fine but it's against the docs.